# AES encrypt/decrypt text

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a text which contains email, username and password and I encrypt it using AES algorithm.

It seems to be ok while I am encrypting, but when it goes to decrypting, only some part (fist 48bytes = 3x 16byte chunks) are ok, but the rest is just some garbage.

I have tried to use unsigned char instead of string, but it had the same problem.

I don't know if the problem is in my algorithm or in charset, but the algorithm seems ok to me.

What if the string contains null terminating character, would it cause problems with string.size? I don't know if the cipher from AES can contain null terminating character.

Here is the code:

```
    int  aes_set_key( aes_context *ctx, uint8 *key, int nbits ); //Prototype
    void aes_encrypt( aes_context *ctx, uint8 input[16], uint8 output[16] ); //Prototype
    void aes_decrypt( aes_context *ctx, uint8 input[16], uint8 output[16] ); //Prototype
    char Buffer[255];
    memset(Buffer, 0, sizeof(Buffer));
    sprintf_s(Buffer, "%s\r\n%s\r\n%s", RegisterEdits[0], RegisterEdits[1], /*PasswordHash.c_str()*/RegisterEdits[2]); // Save email, username and password to buffer
    MSGBOX(Buffer);
    aes_context ctx;
    unsigned char key[] = "0123456789ABCDEF"; // Encrypting/Decrypting key
    unsigned char outputEnc[20];
    unsigned char outputDec[20];
    string CipherData; // Hold whole encrypted text
    string Decrypted; // Hold whole decrypted text
    memset(outputEnc, 0, sizeof(outputEnc));
    memset(outputDec, 0, sizeof(outputDec));
    aes_set_key(&ctx, key, 256);

    int Step = 0;
    char Temp[18];
    do 
    {
        memset(Temp, 0, sizeof(Temp));
        _snprintf(Temp, 16, &Buffer[Step]);//Take first 16 bytes from Buffer at address 0 and copy them into Temp
        Step += strlen(Temp); // Append the Temp size to stepper

        memset(outputEnc, 0, sizeof(outputEnc));
        aes_encrypt(&ctx, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(Temp), outputEnc); // encrypt 16 bytes
        CipherData += reinterpret_cast<char*>(outputEnc); //append the 16 encrypted bytes to string
    } 
    while (Step < strlen(Buffer));
    MSGBOX((LPSTR)CipherData.c_str()); //Let me see the cipher (seems to be ok)

    //Trying little different algorithm than "do while" for decrypting
    MSGBOX("Entering");
    Step = 0;
    for(int i = CipherData.size(); i >= 0; i-=16) //At the start we have cipher size
    {
        if(i < 16) // If we have less than 16 bytes in string left...*
        {
            Beep(1000, 100);
            memset(Temp, 0, sizeof(Temp));
            memcpy(Temp, &CipherData.c_str()[Step], CipherData.size()); // *...copy only the bytes that left.
            MSGBOX(Temp);
            aes_decrypt(&ctx, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(Temp), outputDec);
            Decrypted += reinterpret_cast<char*>(outputDec);
            MSGBOX((LPSTR)Decrypted.c_str());
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //if we do have more than 16 bytes left in the string...
            memset(Temp, 0, sizeof(Temp)); 
            memcpy(Temp, &CipherData.c_str()[Step], 16); // ...Copy 16 bytes again (#)
            MSGBOX(Temp);
            aes_decrypt(&ctx, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(Temp), outputDec); //decrypt 16 bytes
            Decrypted += reinterpret_cast<char*>(outputDec); //append 16 decrypted bytes
            CipherData = SubstractLastn(CipherData, 16); // IMPORTANT! Remove 16 bytes from the end of the string
            Step += 16; // Append decrypted size to stepper
            MSGBOX((LPSTR)Decrypted.c_str());
            //FIX ME! - in 3rd iteration of this loop the CipherData seems to be corrupted in the part marked with (#)
        }
    }
```

I would appriciate any help from you guys!

Comment: Include the crypto library you're working with *in your question please*. And fyi, debuggers were *made* for problems like this.

Comment: I am not using any library, I have just included source codes with AES algorithm written in C by Christophe Devine. I would not post the question if I knew, where is the problem. I don't even think including library would help anyone to solve this type of problem.

Comment: A debugger would near-certainly help. Just to save some time, [this is the algorithm implementation](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/brown/Crypto/src/AES.c) you're using, is that correct? And your issue is very likely that you're treating your *encrypted* data as if it is string-viable. It isn't. AES-encrypted data can be bytes in the full 0..255 range, the first being a major problem the way you're building CipherData. I'll write up an answer, but wanted to make sure I was using the same implementation as you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have been sleeping :P Yes, tahat's the algorithm I'm using...I thought, the reinterpret cast will cast it right and everything will be ok, I am using the same method to send binary data over TCPIP. It would be greatful from you, if you could show me, how to do it right, because I'm still stucked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your treating encrypted data as if it were a terminated string. AES encryption can, and often will, emit a `0x00` octet, and in so doing make any algorithm designed to treat a null-terminated byte sequence as prematurely worthless (so to speak).

The heart of your problem is this:

```
CipherData += reinterpret_cast<char*>(outputEnc);
```

This effectively fires the `operator +=(const char*)` member of `std::basic_string<char>`, which will append your output encoding as if a terminator has been hit. Not good.

I'm not going to attempt to modify your code only because it isn't how I would do this in the first place. Below is a simple (and I stress *simple*) method for encrypting a string.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char key[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    aes_context ctx = {};
    aes_set_key(&ctx, key, 128);

    // some simple message to encrypt
    std::string str = "some simple message to encrypt";

    // will hold out encrypted message
    std::vector<uint8> encryptedBytes;

    // encrypt the data.
    for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end();)
    {
        uint8 plain[16] = {0}, enc[16] = {0};
        size_t i = 0;
        for (; it != str.end() && i < 16; ++i,++it)
            plain[i] = *it;
        aes_encrypt(&ctx, plain, enc);
        encryptedBytes.insert(encryptedBytes.end(), enc, enc+16);
    }

    // now decrypt (not sure if this api requires resetting the
    //  key schedule, but it seems it can't hurt).
    aes_set_key(&ctx, key, 128);
    std::vector<uint8> decrypted;
    for (auto it = encryptedBytes.begin(); it != encryptedBytes.end(); it = std::next(it,16))
    {
        uint8 tmp[16];
        aes_decrypt(&ctx, &(*it), tmp);
        decrypted.insert(decrypted.end(), tmp, tmp+16);
    }

    // rebuild string from data. stop at the terminator or end.
    auto last = std::find(decrypted.begin(), decrypted.end(), 0);
    std::string res(decrypted.begin(), last);

    // show all three (original, cipher, decrypted)
    std::cout << str << '\n';
    print_hex(encryptedBytes.begin(), encryptedBytes.end());
    std::cout << res << '\n';
}
```

This utilizes a brain-dead hex dump that makes a ton of assumptions, so use at your own discretion:

```
template<class Iter>
void print_hex(Iter beg, Iter end)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    unsigned int x = 0;
    while (beg != end)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(*beg) << ' ';
        if (++beg != end && ++x % 16 == 0)
            std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output of the above run using your AES encryption code is the following:

```
some simple message to encrypt
82 56 5b a7 a5 b5 6a e9 e5 a4 a6 9d bb ee 14 db 
6b 1e 54 b8 9d 7f 8c 16 18 c6 33 47 1c f1 48 25 
some simple message to encrypt
```

And finally, a few things to note. First this desperately needs a padding scheme. A commonly used one is [PKCS7 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7), which would be trivial to implement and ensure the exact amount of decrypted text matches the original encryption.

Second, every one of those `16` values you see in this code should be swapped with a manifest constant that is the block size of the algorithm being used. Magic number programming is bad. Don't do as I did; do as you should.

Best of luck.

Comment: Man, you are awesome! Thank you very much! You don't know, how much I appreciate such help!

Comment: Could you please explain me one thing? How did you mean the values should be swapped with manifest constant?

Comment: A macro: `#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE  16`

Comment: Ahhh, I already did that...now I get it, thanks a lot! :) But isn't it a preprocessor constant? Not manifest?
Maybe one more question if you wouldn't mind, how easy would be to crack the encrypted data if I didn't use padding? I have read something about it when you posted it in your answer (heard about it for the first time) and it's just to enhance the encryption?

Comment: The padding isn't there for strengthening encryption; its there to fill-out the block size with data that tells you how big the padding data is. Ex: PKCS7 padding is always added to the last block, or if needed (when your data is already a perfect multiple of the block size) adds an extra block. The link provided will show you how it is used by both the encryptor and the decryptor, which *must* be using the same padding scheme. And yes, poor choice of words on my part. A macro, a `const`, anything that can symbolically communicate the block size rather than littering code with magic numbers.

Comment: In other words the padding is there to elongate the last block if it is under-sized (remember, AES requires 16-octet blocks as part of its scheme). When decrypting, you need a way of knowing how much of the data you just decrypted is *real* data vs padding bytes (so you know what to throw away). The padding algorithm you choose and implement on both the encryptor and decryptor (they must be the same) takes care of that. right now we're just zero-filling, and it will work as-is, but a standard padding algorithm would be better.